# Run command line command in composer.json

Tags: php, json, command-line

I'm trying to write a composer.json file that will run several command line commands in a row so just as an example something like this:

```
"scripts": {
   "test": [
        "@createDir"
   ],
   "createDir": "mkdir testing"

}
```

When I run the composer file in terminal using `composer.phar update` the directory isn't created though. Can anybody point me in the right direction how to do this or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Might want to take a look at the [Events section](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) (pre-update-cmd or post-update-cmd)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Composer doesn't run all scripts by default at the end of an `install` or `update`. For that to happen, your script needs to be under one of the [**Command Event**](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#command-events) keys, e.g. `post-update-cmd`.

You can still reference other scripts within these blocks, e.g.

```
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@test"
    ],
    "test": [
        "touch foo"
    ]
}
```

To run an individual script, you use the `run-script` command:

```
composer run-script test
```

Comment: Also it would be possible with: `composer test`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to run a command that should run for forever this will help you

in composer.json

```
"scripts": {
   
    "start-lumen" : [
        "php -S localhost:8000 -t public"
    ]
}
```

add --timeout=0 to run for forever

```
composer run-script  start-lumen --timeout=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the structure is wrong, let me show you an example:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
    "acacha/admin-lte-template-laravel": "dev-master",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^6.21",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.7.0",
    "spatie/laravel-backup": "^3.0.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "App/Helpers/MyCustomHelper"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
}
```

EDIT: Maybe you can try with `composer dump-autoload`