# Jwt Authentication error Argument 3 passed to Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Hmac::doVerify()

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt

I'm working on a project to learn laravel, I saw a couple of tutorials to use `jwt auth` in this. It was working good but now is show an error not always but I don't know why. this is it:

> Argument 3 passed to Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Hmac::doVerify() must be an instance of Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\inmobiliaria\vendor\lcobucci\jwt\src\Signer\BaseSigner.php on line 42

Sometimes it works but not another. so I don't know what can I do. I tried with

1. php artisan cache:clear
2. php artisan config:clear
3. php artisan jwt:secret

but the problem still there, sometimes i get good answer from server(200) but the most part of then al bad (500).

Screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show code where you're doing the authentication?

Comment: The authentication isn't the problem. This error appear when i try to make class::all(); method in php:

public function all()
    {

        $properties = Property::with('images')->get();
        return response()->json([
            'properties' => $properties
        ], 200);

    }

Comment: Hi @Esteban, I have the same issue, did you find the solution?

Comment: hi @MaxM. Actually no i don't, still looking!

Comment: I have the same issue. 

    Type error: Argument 3 passed to Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Hmac::doVerify() must be an instance of Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key, null given, called in \vendor\lcobucci\jwt\src\Signer\BaseSigner.php on line 42 

It appears when I make many queries (some times it can be with similar params)

Comment: Usually it appears when I make many queries in one moment.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Here's complete snippet

```
php artisan key:generate
php artisan jwt:secret
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Before running the above commands make sure there is an install jwt package, then check its config file name `jwt.php` in the config folder.

Answer (score 31):

In fact it's the right thing to solve it:

```
php artisan key:generate
php artisan jwt:secret
```

Comment: What happen @Esteban?

Comment: @Esteban make sure please you have `'secret' => env('JWT_SECRET'),` and `'passphrase' => env('JWT_PASSPHRASE'),` in your config/jwt.php

Comment: @Esteban on lumen I don't need the config/jwt.php file to work, when using tymon/jwt-auth package. On laravel it's really needed?

Comment: Try this:
1) php artisan cache:clear  
2) php artisan config:clear  
3) php artisan key:generate  
4) php artisan jwt:secret

Answer (score 6):

This error can occur when

- `JWT_SECRET` is missing on the `.env`
- `JWT_SECRET` is commented in the `.env`
- The value of `JWT_SECRET` is wrong.

In my case, running `php artisan jwt:secret` it was appending the key on the current `JWT_SECRET`. So checking my `.env` file, the value of `JWT_SECRET` was very long and wrong (it should be 64 chars long).

To solve it:

1. Open the `.env` and remove the `JWT_SECRET` value (note that you have to remove it and not comment it).
2. Run `php artisan jwt:secret`
3. Run `php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 4):

```
php artisan jwt:secret
php artisan config:cache
```

These both command will be enough

Answer (score 2):

I came across this error when I deployed my application after testing and everything else worked well on the local server.

I noticed the following;

- It's possible that you are getting this error when you uploaded the applications before implementing the JWT and re-uploaded directly via the Cpanel upload without reuploading the .env file.

  - if this is the case, the simplest way to solve this is my merely adding the JWT:key in your .env file (at the bottom) ef

JWT_SECRET=roCZauuldMpw5i4039393939393372y98bEWumqd9ls7Uk8DEpr0gIZ6WIWB

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen when using the Laravel Vapor service if you haven't remembered to add the `JWT_SECRET` to the `env` file used by Vapor.

In that case just pull the `.env` file down for the current environment (in this case `staging`):

`vapor env:pull staging`

and add the `JWT_SECRECT` line to it, followed by a push:

`vapor env:push staging`

and re-deploy.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with my `Laravel 8.x` and `PHP 7.4` so I solved the problem by updating my keys just with these commands:

```
php artisan key:generate
php artisan jwt:secret
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the same on Hostinger - Shared Hosting in a bit different manner than others explained.  On shared hosting's user will not have access to shell/cmd/ssh access to the server - So I have executed the commands using composer - Thanks to Ángel Carlos del Pozo Muela  for sharing the idea in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48682668 for a different solution but it worked in my case here as well

I have updated the composer.json >> script tag with extra  values

```
"scripts": {
    "pre-generate-key": [
        "@php artisan key:generate",
         "@php artisan cache:clear",
        "@php artisan config:clear"
    ],"post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ]
```

Followed by that I have created a new parameter in .env file using going to hostinger file manager   and deployed the changes.

```
 JWT_SECRET={{value}}
```

on successful completion of deployment - Tested the all service -> all services started working fine - then I removed the "pre-generate-key" bit from composer.json and re-deployed code

Answer (score 0):

i'm working on App platform - Digital Ocean `php artisan jwt:secret` does it for me -> it just genarates a new secret and that's what's messing (just check your .env file)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Statement**  :

```
TypeError: Argument 3 passed to Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Hmac::doVerify() m
Facing above problem

Larave version:    8.77
Php Versionn: 7.4
```

**Solution works 100%**

```
php artisan key:generate
php artisan jwt:secret
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution it will work for me

```
php artisan key:generate

php artisan jwt:secret

php artisan cache:clear

php artisan config:clear
```

Before running the above commands make sure there is an install `jwt` package, then check its config file name jwt.php in the config folder